# How to create a button that adds buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html

I have a list of buttons for a web app and I want that when I drag and drop one button it creates a button on the drop location. I don't know how to do that. I know it's supposed to be js but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried creating a button that would allow me to create another button on specific locations but hat it's just not enough, not want I really want.

Comment: Ya, that's not what I asked. I meant the code

Comment: can you please post some more details? as @AshayMandwarya mentioned, some code you have tried etc?